# USB Dongle detected but connect option greyed out

Tags: vmware-server

Hey I have just converted one of our physical license servers into a VMware server. It uses a USB key for a license doggle (WIBU-Key) for some software we have. Now it detects that the USB is plugged in on VMware Server (shows up as Wibu-box) under devices. But when I click on it all the options are greyed out including the connect and as such the VM can't read it? The VM is running Windows Server 2003.

Anyone have any ideas? Ive attached an image so you can see clearer.

Answer (score 1):

My personal experience is that more often than not USB devices do not work properly when connected to the host system. I've had all sorts of issues with USB dongle keys and such.

I ended up buying a Networked USB hub. You stick all your keys and what not in there, install the driver in your windows guest OS, and enter the IP. Your windows server will just treat it as another usb controller.

We have ESX here so an added advantage of this network usb hub is that i can happily migrate those VM's to different servers without having to move usb sticks around on the host device.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What model did you get and which versions of Windows did you get it working with? We're about to have the same issue, so I'd appreciate any specific feedback you have.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is software dongle emulator.